# How does one remove the duplicate console window from Firefox's built-in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I'm currently using Firefox 53.0 (64-bit), which comes with its own implementation of FireBug. Somehow I've ended up in a situation where a second, lower console pane displays under my main FireBug panel. (See the yellow area in the attached pic.) For my screen height, this takes up valuable vertical space that I don't have to spare. Is there a way to close the lower console pane? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the split console by clicking the related toggle button [image: Split console toggle button] or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (so their official name) are focused.

*Note: The reason why those tools look somewhat like Firebug is that they have a [Firebug theme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings#Themes) integrated. There's [more information about this integration in the Mozilla hacks blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).*

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. It was right there... I don't know why I didn't see it.)